# Auto deploy from github repo to web host

Tags: reactjs, git, github, hosting, gatsby

I'm currently trying to setup auto deploy from a Github repository to my webhost provider. I achieved this before with Netlify, but I want to host my website at my hosting provider and not Netlify.

I've no idea where to start and even my provider didn't know if it was possible.

Webhost provider: TransIP (it's dutch) 
Project: Gatsby + ReactJS

I can access the hosting server with (s)ftp. I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby requires an HTTP server such as Nginx, Apache or Node.js HTTP server. Anything that can host static HTML files. This is essentially what is runnning at Netlify in the background.

You can use your FTP access to move your Gatsby files to your server. I used to host Gatsby on a Linux root server which had Nginx as an HTTP server. You move the content of the  `/public` folder that is produced after you run `gatsby build` to the `www` folder of your server. This [blog](https://dev.to/teamxenox/deploy-a-static-site-in-3-steps-5dag) describes the method I used pretty good.

My advice is to keep using netlify or any other static hosting provider. It's much easier, faster, more reliable and removes the work you spend on setting up your deployment pipeline.

I don't speak dutch. Ask your hosting provider if they have an "HTTP server" or a way to host "static HTML, CSS and Javascript".

Comment: Thank you for the response. My hosting provider does have a HTTP server where I can push static HTML, CSS and JS files to. That's how I currently doing it. But next to the domein, I bought hosting from them. That's why I don't want to use netlify to be honest. 

I know I can run built withing the gatsby/react app and upload the files after. But the goal is: 
To push the project to Github, run the built automatically, and publish it to the HTTP server of my hosting provider.

Comment: The hosting provider couldn't help me further, but they do have an API:
https://api.transip.nl/rest/docs.html?&_ga=2.215142229.336398375.1588963840-354013794.1586091879#introduction

I found something like this: https://github.com/marketplace/deliverybot & https://github.com/marketplace/actions/ftp-deploy

But it isn't working yet.